# Should I make calculations using Ruby, or should I make them using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, greatest-n-per-group

I'm building a reporting system for a chat made in Ruby on Rails but received some comments telling me that my approach is inefficient.

Here's a little sample of how my reports work:

I have a handler that is called each month which calls a Report mailer Like this:

```
ReportMailer.monthly_report(user).deliver_later
```

This is how the mailer looks:

```
class ReportMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: ENV["DEFAULT_MAILER_FROM"],
          template_path: 'mailers/report_mailer'

  def monthly_report(agent)
    @agent = agent
    @organization = agent.organization
    @report = Report.new @organization
    mail(to: agent.email, subject: @report.email_subject)
  end
end
```

I'm trying to calculate the data using a "plain old" Ruby class:

```
module Reports
  class Component < Report

    def initialize(subject)
      @component = subject
      @cache = {}
    end

    attr_reader :component

    # DELEGATIONS
    # -----------------------

    delegate :chat_messages, to: :component

    def response_count
      count = 0
      explore_msgs { |msg, next_msg| count += 1 if response? msg, next_msg }
      return count
    end

    def response_time
      time = 0
      explore_msgs { |msg, next_msg| time += time_difference msg, next_msg if response? msg, next_msg }
      return time.to_i.seconds
    end

    def avg_response_time
      @cache[__method__] ||= (response_time / response_count if response_count > 0)
    end

    private

    def response?(msg, next_msg)
      next_msg&.user_type == 'Agent' && msg.user_type == 'User' && msg.conversation_id == next_msg.conversation_id && time_difference(msg, next_msg).seconds < 8.hours
    end

    def time_difference(msg, next_msg)
      (next_msg.created_at - msg.created_at).abs
    end

    def explore_msgs
      chat_messages.each_with_index do |msg, i| 
        next_msg = chat_messages[i+1]
        yield msg, next_msg
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I'm concerned with improving performance. I implemented a simple caching system into the class in charge of making the calculations which made huge improvements in the system efficiency, however, I'm concerned that making these calculations in Ruby might create bottlenecks or that it might not be a scalable solution.

Comment: With about 10 years of XP in web development, I came to the conclusion that the DB is (almost) always better for (almost) any operation (group, sort, count, calculate, aggregate, search, etc). You may want to persist the computation in a `SQL` view (or materialized views) or have it live in your Rails code.

Comment: One caution here.  Because of what you are doing, you run the risk of building a co-related query, which can be a slow database operation.  So if you are trying to have faster database processing than ruby, be sure to avoid co-related queries.

Comment: As @MrYoshiji said, do as much as you can in the database rather than retrieve raw data and use Ruby to process it. A DBM contains very optimized code for DB-related things so let it do them because it's closer to the data. Moving data impacts your network, drives, and CPU on your Rails machine that really needs to focus on running Rails and handling requests. Also, it sounds like you're differentiating Rails from Ruby; Rails IS Ruby code, Ruby processes it so there's no difference unless you're rewriting wheels that the Rails code does better.

Answer (score 0):

It could be faster.  The problem I see is that you are looking a one record and the following record.  So how would you get the database to compare the two records?

In straight SQL, I would join the table to itself, group by the first instance of the table and do a min(created_at) on the second instance of the table.

Using our `companies` table, the SQL looks like this:

```
select rc1.id, rc1.created_at, min(rc2.created_at)
from companies rc1 inner join companies rc2 on rc1.created_at < rc2.created_at
group by rc1.id
```

You can add the difference to the select.

This will be certainly be slow if the `created_at` field is not indexed and the number of records in the table is large.

You can add the test for `Agent` and `User` to the having clause.

The query is tricky and the database might not be able to do this fast.  It will also be tricky if you try to get ActiveRecord to build the query for you.

However, I think everything you are trying to do in your code can be done this way by the database.

Your query might look like this:

```
select chat_messages.*,
       min(next_msg.created_at) as next_created_at,
       next_msg.created_at - chat_messages.created_at as created_at_diff
from chat_messages inner join chat_messages next_msg
  on chat_messages.created_at < chat_messages.created_at
     and chat_messages.user_type = 'User'
group by chat_messages.id
having next_msg.user_type = 'Agent'
   and TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, min(next_msg.created_at), chat_messages.created_at) < 8
```

Comment: Create an index on the fields `user_type, created_at`.

Comment: Correction, you should have two indexes.  One on `user_type` and one on `created_at`.